# bundle command not found heroku

Tags: heroku, bundler

I am trying to use ruby 1.8.7 in my heroku application but the application does not launch. Heroku shows following errors in the console:

```
2012-10-30T13:29:08+00:00 app[web.2]: bash: bundle: command not found
```

`heroku run "bundle --version"` also returns in command not found:

```
heroku run "bundle --version"
Running `bundle --version` attached to terminal... up, run.1
bash: bundle: command not found
```

Any ideas on what might be issue here ?

Answer (score 2):

The code will look like this with the newest version:

```
heroku config:add GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a new ruby version? Good chance that ruby version doesnt have bundler installed, use

```
heroku run 'gem install bundler'
```

after installing a new ruby!

Comment: Yes, I installed a new ruby version and then executed heroku run 'gem install bundler'. It said that it installed bundler 1.2.1 but still shows that error in the logs ..

Comment: you could try using `sudo gem install bundler` to install it on the root instead of the user

Comment: You can try setting the correct path by adding `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to your .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the supported Ruby buildpack set:
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby`